# java jdbc question

Tags: jdbc

how to retrieve data from table and store in notepad ?
how is it possible in jdbc?

Comment: man !! you have to be clear what type of Database are you using.How far you had achieved or where you are failing.

Answer (score 1):

```
FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("c:\file_name.txt");
PrintStream print = new PrintStream(file);
ResultSet rs = statement.exexuteQuery("select  * from Table_name");

while(re.next()!= -1)
{
    rs.setOut(print);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must query your database, then retrieve it using [ResultSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) interface. Of course you need JDBC driver to your database (or you can use JDBC-ODBC bridge).

Storing results in notepad is strange for me. You can save results in text file that can be opened by notepad, or use system clipboard to save results. See: [Class Clipboard](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html). Your app can transfer data to clipboard, and then notepad user can paste it (Ctrl+V) to notepad window.